# Filter on multi-select on Active Admin (Rails 3.2/postgreSQL/active admin 1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I run into a problem while trying to filter on a resource on Active Admin.

Filters actually work perfectly when I apply them to standard stuff but here it's a **multi-select**.

Indeed in my Deals model: There is a "Deal_goal" attribute and I can choose many Deal_goal such as "acquire new users", or "generate buzz"

Here is how I input it on my active admin form:

```
f.input :deal_goal,
        :label      => "Deal goals",
        :as         => :select,
        :multiple   => true,
        :collection => DEAL_GOALS
```

**To make the multi select, I serialize it on my Deal model**

app/models/deal.rb

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :deal_goal, Array
```

I am also using [staal.io advice for multi-selects](http://staal.io/blog/2013/02/26/mastering-activeadmin/) (the 'chosen' gem)

What I fail to do is on my index page (list of deals), to have a filter on my Deal_goal attribute and if possible to have a multi-select here enabling me to filter on deals based on more than one type of goal (for example: filter deals with goal#1 or goal#3)

I tried both of what is below on admin/deal.rb and none worked!

```
filter :deal_goal,    :as => :select, :collection => DEAL_GOALS
filter :deal_goal,    :as => :multiple_select, :collection => DEAL_GOALS
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a multiple select in the same way you do in your form, with `multiple: true`:

```
filter :deal_goal, as: :select, collection: DEAL_GOALS, multiple: true
```

### UPDATE

Querying PostgreSQL arrays from Active Admin / Ransack can be done, it just takes a bit more work. First off, you should add the [postgres_ext](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem to your Gemfile. It gives you a nice set of query methods that you can use like this:

```
User.where.contains roles: ['foo']
# or:
User.where User.arel_table[:roles].contains ['foo']
```

The next step is to tell Ransack that these query methods (or "predicates") exist. Put this in an initializer:

```
# https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/321
Ransack.configure do |config|
  { array_contained_within:           :contained_within,
    array_contained_within_or_equals: :contained_within_or_equals,
    array_contains:                   :contains,
    array_contains_or_equals:         :contains_or_equals,
    array_overlap:                    :overlap
  }.each do |rp, ap|
    config.add_predicate rp, arel_predicate: ap, wants_array: true
  end
end
```

You can confirm that Ransack is picking up on the added methods if this:

```
User.search(roles_contains: [3,4]).result.to_sql
```

Generates this SQL:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."roles" @> '{"3","4"}')
```

Now to get these new methods working with Active Admin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :roles_array_contains, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ['foo', 'bar']
end
```

Of course, be sure to change `User` and `roles` to the model and attribute that fits your situation.

One final note. I noticed you're manually setting up `serialize :attr, Array` in your model. For your array to be a PostgreSQL array you have to specify `array: true` in the database migration. Assuming you've already done that, then this `serialize` call is unnecessary. In fact, it seems to break this approach for some reason, so be sure to remove it.

Comment: i tested it and it doesn't work. Actually i thing to debug this i need to make it work even for a "normal i.e "non multi" select FILTER on my multi-select ATTRIBUTE" deal_goals. According to me, the problem is that the multi select filter works when the attribute is normal but here it's a an array of values and it doesn' seem to work in that case.

Comment: The issue is probably that you're using a serialized array. Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: yes as i have put on my question i serialize it to include many values (inside a constant). yes i am using postgresql. do you think it's an issue with postgresql ?

Comment: I tried to check on the web but didn't find valuable resource on a postgresql problem ... would you already have heard about it? do you know any website mentioning how to solve it?

Comment: @Mathieu I just updated my answer with an in-depth guide to setting up PostgreSQL array searches. Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: testing it now, thanks for the extra insight : i throught i had to do it the classic way "serialize: Array" . i had no clue i could do it straight on the db migration and that it would actually be cleaner. thanks!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it modifies string column contains (etc) predicates to use array, which creates invalid SQL.  The way to deal with this is to create array specific predicates for ransack, which then map to arel / wants_array predicates.

Comment: @Slomojo you're right, and I'd actually updated my own use of this code to do that a while back. I just updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for mentioning it!